# How to calculate the Fourier series of $\sin x-4\sin 3x+7$

Tags: fourier-series

How to calculate the Fourier series of $\sin x-4\sin 3x+7$

I obtain $0$ por the an and bn coeficients, and I think that's incorrect...

Comment: What is $sen$? $\sin$?

Comment: That already is a Fourier series.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Samuel said in a comment, the function is already in the Fourier series form. Recall that your goal is to write the function $f(x)$ as

$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1\cos x + b_1 \sin x + a_2\cos 2x + b_2 \sin 2x + a_3\cos 3x + b_3 \sin 3x + \cdots
$$

Can you see why your function is already in this form? Can you see the only 3 coefficients that are not zero?

Comment: no, I can't see that 3 coefficients

Comment: There are 3 terms in your function that appear also in the expansion I wrote (for a suitable choice of the coefficients). Does this help?